# Quicksort returning unsorted array

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion

I have two days trying to figure out why my quicksort function returns all but two elements sorted in correct order.

With the Input

```
quicksort([0,7,3,11,23,87,999,1023,12,713,5,6,9])
```

Outputs

```
[0, 6, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 23, 87, 713, 999, 1023]
```

What do you think is wrong with the function?

```
def quicksort(array):
    #Base case
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    #Choose pivot always at the left part and partition array around it
    Pivot = partition(array,0,len(array));
    #Add values for left and righ arrays
    left = array[:Pivot]
    right = array[Pivot+1:]
    #Add recursive calls
    left = quicksort(left)
    right = quicksort(right)
    #Append Pivot at the end of left array
    left.append(array[Pivot])
    return left+right
```

For matters of completion I'm adding the partition function but I'm almost sure the issue is not there.

```
def partition(array,left,right):
    #If pivot is not on leftmost, swap to make it leftmost
    Pivot = array[left]
    i = left+1
    for j in range(left+1,right):
        if array[j] < Pivot:
            #Swap array[j] and array[i]
            array[j], array[i] = array[i], array[j]
            i += 1;
    #Swap pivot and A[i-1]        
    array[left], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[left]
    return left
```

Comment: Your current code also fails on sorting [3,1,2] if you wish to use a simpler example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition function always returns the `left` argument, as it was supplied without changing it. I think you intend to return the final position of the pivot element.

Comment: I love you, I thought I implemented the partition function perfect but I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion, making use of pythons comprehension lists, makes the code much simpler to implement and read.

```
def qs(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return l
    pivot = l.pop()
    left = [x for x in l if x < pivot]
    right = [x for x in l if x >= pivot]
    return qs(left) + [pivot] + qs(right)
```

It reads pretty much like the pseudo-code found in text books.

1. Lists of size 1 or 0 are sorted by definition
2. Choose a Pivot. In this case it's the last element
3. Create two partitions so that one has all the elements smaller than the pivot and the other has the elements greater then or equal to the pivot
4. Recursively call quicksort on both partitions and append the results with the pivot in the middle